# FOREACH not preparing PDO statement at each iteration

Tags: php, sql, foreach, pdo

I am trying to run a FOREACH with PDO but so far my code seems to iterate only once for the FOREACH and returns only the 1st value.

Here is what I have:

```
$colors = $_GET['color'];
$colors = explode(' ', $colors);
foreach ($colors as $color) 
    {
    $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
    $items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
    }
$items ->execute();
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo $info['color_base1'];
}
```

Note that $colors contains more than 1 different color obtained from checkboxes and a jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's more likely that it's the last value rather than the first. You are basically overwriting your binding in each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is nested wrong: you want to prepare the query once, and execute it multiple times, but you're doing the opposite.

Rather than:

```
foreach ( ... )
{
    prepare( ... );
    bind( ... );
}
execute();
```

You need:

```
prepare( ... );
foreach ( ... )
{
    bind( ... );
    $results[] = execute();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an SQL `IN` clause to build one query rather than having the overhead of going back and forth to the database multiple times.

Comment: How would the SQL look with the IN? Also, I understand that I have to bring the PREPARE out of the FOREACH, but Why do I have to EXECUTE inside the loop and not after?

Comment: Because each time you bind the parameter, you have to execute the query to get the corresponding data. Also, another mistake you made was using bindValue when you should be using bindParam.

Comment: Think of `bindValue` like assigning a variable: each time round the loop, you are setting a new value for the `:colorbase1` parameter, but you are not doing anything with it. You need to run `execute` each time for it to actually be sent to the database before you overwrite it with a different value.

Comment: As for `IN`, I'll leave the PHP for you or some other kind-hearted soul, but the SQL you end up with would look something like `SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN ('blue', 'green', 'red')`

Comment: @IMSoP - The thing is that I had multiple IFs that prepare different SQL queries each time. And at the end, before showing results, I was EXECUTING whatever was prepared before. So you mean I should EXECUTE independently inside each IF?

Comment: Yes. The `execute` call outside the loop is only running one SQL query; there is nothing keeping track of the different queries you are preparing.

Comment: @IMSoP - Thanks. Do you recommend using a FOREACH or I should rather use the SQL IN? Thanks!

Comment: It's generally good practice to avoid running SQL in a loop for performance reasons: even a very quick call to the database carries some overhead as the script connects to the server and data is sent back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```
<?php 
//Check your vars before setting!
$colors = (!empty($_GET['color'])?$_GET['color']:null);
$colors = explode(' ', $colors);

//Prepare the query once
$items = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase");
//Use bindParam then you can set $color later on
$items->bindParam(":colorbase", $color);

//Execute the query, iterating over each color
$results=array();
foreach ($colors as $color){
    $items->execute();
    //Fetch the result and store in $results
    $results[] = $items->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

//Loop through results
if(!empty($results)){
    foreach($results as $result) {
        foreach($result as $row){
            echo $row['color_base1'].'<br />';
        }
    }
}else{
    //empty
}
?>
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but (IMHO) it's better to give a simplified explanation than complete code which the questioner may not fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to provide a `print_r` of the `$_GET['color']` ?

The reason for this - I think that if you have spaces in the q string it will not progress any further that the 1st space therefore the foreach will only run only once.